# How to run example from developer.twitter.com

Tags: curl, twitter, sttwitterapi

I've just seen snippet of code on developer.twitter.com

```
  'curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/<ENV>.json \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN>' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
                "query":"from:TwitterDev lang:en",
                "maxResults": "100",
                "fromDate":"<YYYYMMDDHHmm>", 
                "toDate":"<YYYYMMDDHHmm>"
                }'
```

[page of api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/quick-start/premium-30-day)

Using cmd command line or Windows power shell i receive error because of multiline format of the code. However everything is ok for string without line breaks.

My question is - Where i can run this snippet of code without errors?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please share the error you are facing. This will help others to help you or ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

This command works in bash and zsh on Linux and Mac - I have not been able to test it on Windows. In PowerShell, the multi-line continuation character is backtick `. Remember to replace the `<ENV>` and `<BEARER_TOKEN>` values and to edit or remove the `fromDate` and `toDate` parameters. Also, the leading single quote is not from the documentation page, so you'll need to remove that as well.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Of course i know about  replacement. I'm just surprised, that twitter declares "copy and run" and does not point out where and how. Direct way for windows user does not work.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - I'll add this to our documentation suggestions.